# Alternative phrasing of "Older History"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm writing an essay which I want to divide into 3 parts. The first will detail events from the recent past (past decade), the second will go further back in history (past century) and the third will go back many millions of years. I'd like to title these three parts something like "History", "Older History", "Even Older History", but this sounds kinda clunky.

What would be a better titling scheme that achieves this effect?

Comment: Perhaps recent history, ancient history and antediluvian history.

Comment: @WeatherVane which flood did you have in mind?

Comment: @djs any of them?

Comment: Contemporary history - modern history - ancient history?

Comment: Modern history and ancient history have specific meanings, so don't use them in a non standard way.

Comment: If you're going back to a time before humans, you'll need something other than *history* or *prehistory* — which are words relative to humans.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, the Zanclean Flood meets the criterion of many millions of years for H's third group, but, say, the Yellow River Flood of 1938 or the Great Molasses Flood of 1919 would fall into the second. What I'm trying to say is that we shouldn't project our notions of past events on H's text

Comment: @djs you don't need to use it with its literal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

History, antecedent history, ancient(or remote or earlier or former) history.

Antecedent [free dictionary:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/antecedent) One that precedes another.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a History essay, do you need to repeat that in every heading?

From your question it appears to me that you mean specific time periods. Unless the time periods you refer to have well-known names, like “Renaissance” or “Triassic”, it would be clearer to simply use them as titles.

**This Decade**, **This Century**, **Long Ago**?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wax poetic?

- Years Ago
- Days of Old
- Eons Back